# Debug Classic ASP via IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I'm having a problem showing detailed errors for classic ASP pages. Initially it just showed default 500 error page, we then followed the instructions [here](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/10/19/Improving-Custom-Errors-for-IIS7-Server.aspx)

but now it only shows:

> An error occurred on the server when
>   processing the URL. Please contact the
>   system administrator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eduardo, we did have Send Errors To Browser set to True for the website. I believe a parent setting was overriding this. When updating the parents value it corrected the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Inside IIS, select ASP, and then change `Send errors to browser` to **Yes**

[alt text http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/6749/capturets.png](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/6749/capturets.png)